# Login with user's subscriber role in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Want only subscriber's role user login into the app. I have no idea to get subscriber role in wordpress..  Here is my code

```
$u_name = $_POST['userName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $u_name;

//$tokenID = $_GET['tokenID'];
$vendor_list = array();
if ( username_exists( $username ) ) 
    {

       $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

       if ( $user && wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID) ) 
        {
        $email = $user->user_email;
        $vendor_list[] = array("userID"=>$user->ID,"userName" =>$username,"email" =>$email);
        echo json_encode($vendor_list);
        }
        else 
        {
        $testing = 2;
        echo json_encode($testing);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $testing = 1;
        echo json_encode($testing);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$u_name = $_POST['userName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $u_name;

//$tokenID = $_GET['tokenID'];
$vendor_list = array();
if ( username_exists( $username ) ) 
    {

       $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

       if ( $user && wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID) && ) 
        {
        $users = wp_get_current_user();
            if(in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $users->roles ) )
            {
                $email = $user->user_email;
                $vendor_list[] = array("userID"=>$users->ID,"userName" =>$username,"email" =>$email);
                echo json_encode($vendor_list);
            }
            else
            {
                $testing = 3;
                echo json_encode($testing);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
        $testing = 2;
        echo json_encode($testing);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $testing = 1;
        echo json_encode($testing);
    }
```

Comment: Hello Ash, Thanks for the reply but can you please let me know how do i use this in my code. where do i use this condition?

Comment: after query : $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username ); you can use this code and apply condition base on user role in your code.

Comment: It is showing the null result.. i just want to login only the users who have subscriber role. 

{"success":1,"result":null,"error":"No Error Found"}

Comment: I have just copy and paste the code provided by you but it is showing same error

{"success":1,"result":null,"error":"No Error Found"}

Comment: can you print result after $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username ); and $users = wp_get_current_user(); and check what you are getting from database?